# Print Image in a Double Sided Paper using window.print()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two images:

```
<img id="sample1" src="front.jpg"></img>
<img id="sample2" src="back.jpg"></img>
```

I want to print `sample1` in front of the paper and `sample2` in the back of the paper, how will I do that using javascript/window.print()?

My printer is capable of printing double sided printing.

Comment: First you'd need a printer capable of printing on both sides.

Comment: Do you have any Javascript so far?

Comment: @ScottHunter --obcourse, I have and what's next?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to use css that splits images onto separate pages

```
@media print {
    img {page-break-after: always;}
}
```

That will separate your images onto separate pages for print only. Then tell your print dialog to print duplex